# ogr2ogr geometryCollection export: Attempt to write non-linestring (GEOMETRYCOLLECTION) geometry to ARC type shapefile

Tags: gdal, shapefile, export, ogr2ogr, geometrycollection

I'm trying to export a single table row to geometryCollection.
I don't understand why I am getting the following error message or how to fix it.

The row contains the following shape GEOMETRYCOLLECTION field:

GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (310657.78 389649.39), POLYGON ((310657.78 389641.12, 310811.86 389642.16, 310810.83 389653.53, 310657.78 389649.39, 310657.78 389641.12)))

**Error message:**

`ERROR 1: Attempt to write non-linestring (GEOMETRYCOLLECTION) geometry to ARC type shapefile. ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 0 from layer SELECT. ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed`

**Argument:**

-f "ESRI Shapefile" "[File_path]" "MSSQL:driver=Odbc Driver 11 For SQL Server;server=[server];database=[database];UID=[user];PWD=[password];trusted_connection=yes" -sql "Select * from [view_name]"  -overwrite -lco "

Comment: ESRI shapefiles do not support geometrycollections at all https://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/mo_/shapefile.pdf. You must discard your geometry or split it and save the point into a point type shapefile, polygon into polygon type shapefile.

Comment: that will explain it! thanks for the heads up